# Insert text to xenforo editor with redactor api

Tags: redactor, xenforo

With document.ready event I want add a string = 'bla bla bla' to redactor editor in xenforo
i'm try

```
$('#ctrl_message_html').redactor('set', 'Your text goes here');
$('#ctrl_message_html').redactor('inserttext', 'Your text goes here');
```

but it don't have any effect...pls guide me how to insert it with xenfor redactor editor
thank you very much!